# Phone has been hanging a lot after updating to 8.1

Tags: lumia, 8.1, lumia-520

Ever since I have upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1, my Lumia 520 has been hanging a lot. When it happens, the phone just freezes everything on the screen and nothing happens until I take out the battery, re-install and restart it. This happens every 2 to 3 days.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would not advice you to switch back to 8.0

Comment: Since it's a Developer Preview things like that were espected to happen. I think you only can wait for RTM.

Comment: everything is frozen, or just the touchscreen? for me the buttons do work, so i guess it is a problem with the lockscreen app, mainly

Comment: Same issue for me on 925. Have to soft reset the phone every 2-3 days.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

Most issues resulting from an update to Windows Phone 8.1 can be fixed by doing a [hard reset](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone).